# Convert table indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, matrix

I have data in an array thats get populated into a table. The index of the array corresponds to its spot in the table like so:

```
0,1,2        0,1,2       0,1,2
3,4,5    or  3,4,5   or  3,4,5
6,7,8        6,7         6
```

Which is to say it is ordered left to right, top to bottom. I need to come up with a function that will order it top to bottom, left to right. Like this:

```
0,3,6      
1,4,7
2,5,8
```

A couple of things to note. The table can have any number of elements in it, but will only ever have 3 columns.

So to summarize, I need something like this:

```
Array indexes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Indexes after converting= [0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8]
```

Now I have this working for some cases, like if there are nine values. Im just really struggling to figure this out for an arbitrary case. Im using Javascript, but really any answer in any language would help.

Reasoning for this, is I need my table layed out differently, but dont want to touch the html. I want to reorder the indexes so they will be layed out top to bottom, left to right.

Heres what I have so far:

```
    scope.correctIndexData = function (data) {
        var colors = ['#92278f', '#f15a29', '#006838', '#27aae1', '#262262', '#754c29', '#ee2a7b', '#8dc63f', '#fff200'];
        var row = 0;
        var column = 0;

        var correctedData = new Array(data.length);
        for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
           var newIndex = scope.getCorrectedIndex(row,column,data);
            if(data.length>=10){
                correctedData[index] = data[newIndex];
            }
            else{
                correctedData[newIndex] = data[index];
                correctedData[newIndex].color = colors[newIndex];
            }

            if (column === 2) {
                column = 0;
                row++;
            } else {
                column++;
            }
        }
        return correctedData;
    };

    scope.getCorrectedIndex = function (row, column, data) {
        var newIndex;
        var rows = Math.ceil(data.length/3.0); //number of rows in table
        //handle the first row since there can be verying number of columns per row
        if (row === 0) { 
            if(column === 0){
                newIndex = 0;
            }
            else if (column === 1) {
                newIndex = rows;
            } else if(column == 2){
                if(data.length % 3 == 1){
                    newIndex = rows * 2 -1;
                }
                else{
                newIndex = rows * 2;    

            }
        }
        } else {
            if(data.length % 3 === 0){
                newIndex = (row) + (3 * column);
            }
            else if(data.length % 3 == 1){
                if(column === 0 || data.length % 7 === 0){
                    newIndex = (row) + (3 * column);
                }
                else{
                    newIndex = (row) + (3 * column) + 1;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(column === 0){
                    newIndex = (row) + (3 * column);
                }
                else{
                    newIndex = (row) + (3 * column) + 2;
                }
            }
        }
        return newIndex;
    };
```

Comment: So the length of the input array will always be 7, 8 or 9?

Comment: It could be any length. I just used those as an example.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying. So the only restriction is always 3 columns.

Comment: What would be the expected output array for the input, `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` ?

Comment: @user489041 I don't understand _why_ that's the desired behavior. That doesn't follow the transposition algorithm you described at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
// for your case, columns should equal 3
function transpose(array, columns) {
  var output = [];
  var rows = Math.ceil(array.length / columns);
  var i, j;

  for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows && i * columns + j < array.length; i++) {
      output.push(array[i * columns + j]);
    }
  }

  return output;
}

var input = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

console.log(input.slice(0, 9).join());
console.log(transpose(input.slice(0, 9), 3).join());
console.log('----');
console.log(input.slice(0, 8).join());
console.log(transpose(input.slice(0, 8), 3).join());
console.log('----');
console.log(input.slice(0, 7).join());
console.log(transpose(input.slice(0, 7), 3).join());
console.log('----');
console.log(input.slice(0, 12).join());
console.log(transpose(input.slice(0, 12), 4).join());
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

The second argument also allows you to specify how many columns you're transposing with as I demonstrated in the last example.

## Edit

I don't really understand why you want `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` to transpose to `[0,3,5,1,4,6,2]`, so I will try and explain why it seems logical that the result should actually be `[0,3,6,1,4,2,5]`:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6
```

Following your transposition algorithm, you should trace the numbers first top-to-bottom, then left-to-right, like this:

```
0 3 6
1 4
2 5
```

Then, when you flatten that into an array by reading left-to-right, then top-to-bottom, you get:

```
0 3 6 1 4 2 5
```

Which is exactly what my algorithm does. If you could explain why you concluded the answer should be `0 3 5 1 4 6 2`, then that would help me adjust my algorithm the way you want.

Comment: Ok, I gave this a go. It works in most cases except when there are 7 indexes. Thanks so much for this though

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate by column (ie by every 3rd member)

```
scope.extract = function (data, col) {
  var ar = [];
  for (var i = col; i < data.length; i += 3) {
    ar.push(data[i]);
  }
  return ar;
}

scope.correctIndexData = function (data) {
  return scope.extract(data, 0).concat(scope.extract(data, 1)).concat(scope.extract(data,2))
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but I don't think this works for the third case (7 items).